# How do I serve HTML from cgi-bin?

Tags: html, bash, cgi, sh, openwrt

I am running uhttpd on OpenWrt 12.09. I have a shell script at /www/cgi-bin/test that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "<p>It works!</p>"
```

I gave the file execute permissions by doing `chmod +x` on it. Owner is root, and uhttpd is running as root.

Now when I go to `http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/test` I get an error:

```
The CGI process did not produce any response
```

There are no errors in the system or kernel logs.

I can go to `http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/luci` and get the LuCI login page, so other CGI scripts are working. That file has a different shebang (`#!/usr/bin/lua`) but both scripts have the same permissions and owner.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There **must** be a blank line between the HTTP header and the body. Also, you might want to serve up a complete html document.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo 
echo "<html><head><title>hello world</title></head><body><p>It works!</p></body></html>"
```

Comment: Try with exit 0 at the end of the script

Comment: What about my code will cause a non-zero exit status?